# Jest Test TypeORM EntityManager cannot retreive inserted entities

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, entitymanager, typeorm

I'm running integration tests similar to this, if I try to check database contents the query do not find inserted rows. Does the EntityManager use different connections? Or do I need to "flush" in some ways (I do no know how)?

The manager.save works with success, I see in typeORM logs the insert without errors and generated *id* of entities are filled.

```
   test('should be retrieved ', async () => {
            const manager = getManager();
        
            await manager.save(item_1);
        
            const result = await manager.createQueryBuilder()
            .select()
            .from(EntityTypeX, "x")
            .getMany();
        
            expect(result).toHaveLength(1) //This return zero
        
          });
..
    beforeAll( async () => {
        return opneDBCconnection();
    });
    beforeEach( async () => {
       // Clenaup
       getManager().createQueryBuilder()
      .delete()
      .from(Sms)
      .execute();    
    });
```

Comment: `async` without `await` is going to bite you.

Comment: thx, where I have to put await ? in the beforeEach or in the beforeAll ?

Comment: `beforeEach` `await getManager().createQueryBuilder()....` but you should remove the `async` from `beforeAll(async () => ` or add an `await` for consistency.

Comment: Same result , I also tried to remove the "return" adding the await in beforeAll

Comment: I wasn't saying that was what was causing this specific issue but that you had a bug that you should fix